# factorial of a number greater than high

Tags: matlab

Write a function that will find the factorial greater than the input argument high.
Here is the function but I wonder why 'i' is initialized to 0 instead of 1,help?

```
function facgt = factgthigh(high)
% factgthigh returns the first factorial > input
% Format: factgthigh(inputInteger)
i=0;
fac=1;
while fac <= high
i=i+1;
fac = fac * i;
end
facgt = fac;
end
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you didn't write this code, and you need help tracing it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  There are a some things you should understand about this site and how to ask questions. This is not a forum where you should post your assignments and code you would like generally reviewed. Please [ask a specific programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Please read on [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Importantly see [this post on how to ask homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you add 1 to i before you multiply, i has to start at 0.

If you instead did

```
fac = fac * i;
i=i+1;
```

Then i could start at 1, though starting at 0 still wouldn't be harmful to the function (though less efficient).

Comment: and what is the fac of 0? is it 1?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is incremented (+1) as the first line inside the while loop.